# Remove specific row from Quasar's table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar-framework, quasar

I read the documentation of Quasar but I didn't see any instruction to remove a specific row from a table. For example, how can I remove the selected row from its table?
I want to know how can to do it in the script part, not in the HTML segment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `splice` by using index of a `row` to remove the row.

```
methods:{
    deleteSelected(){
      let self = this;
      this.selected.filter(function(item){
        self.data.splice(self.data.indexOf(item), 1);
        return item;
      });
      this.selected = [];
    },
    deleteval(index){
      console.log(index)
      this.data.splice(index, 1);

      console.log(this.data)
    }
  }

<template v-slot:top-right>
        <q-btn
          color="primary"
          icon-right="delete_forever"
          no-caps
          @click="deleteSelected"
        />
      </template>
       <template v-slot:body-cell-action="props">
        <q-td :props="props">
          <q-btn
          color="negative"
          icon-right="delete"
          no-caps
          flat
          dense
          @click="deleteval(data.indexOf(props.row))"
        />
        </q-td>
      </template>
```

Working codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/eYNvvva?editable=true&editors=101

Comment: Why using props.row (object) works in array.splice which expects first parameter to be int?

Comment: I have used index not Object in splice.

Comment: `@click="deleteval(props.row)"` here props.row is an object right?

Comment: Yes props.row is Object

Comment: So -> `@click="deleteval(props.row)"` -> `deleteval(index){` -> `this.data.splice(index, 1);` -> you are passing an object as an splice first argument right?

Answer (score 0):

you can use splice() . other methods like pop(), remove() is not correct for expectation

Comment: The code you posted is *not* a runnable snippet (just click the "Run..." button and you will realize that)! Please edit your answer and format your code as a **plain code block** instead (use simple, three back-tick code fences).